# Having trouble inserting dates into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to insert some dates (a given date, +1 day and +1 month) into MySQL with PHP (CI).

Here is my CI active record code:

the variable `$last_period_end` returns `2012-02-20`, the field it is trying to insert it into is MySQL `DATE` format.

```
$data = array(
            'user_id'       =>  $user_id,
            'period_start'  =>  "DATE_ADD($last_period_end, INTERVAL 1 DAY)",
            'period_end'    =>  "DATE_ADD($last_period_end, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)",
            'cost'          =>  $cost
        );

    $result = $this->db->insert('invoices', $data);

    if ( $result )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

This inserts `0000-00-00` rather than what I would like it to.

I have also tried pure SQL:

```
INSERT INTO betterbill.invoices (user_id, period_start, period_end, cost)
VALUES(18, DATE_ADD(2012-02-20, INTERVAL 1 DAY), DATE_ADD(2012-02-20, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 100.05);
```

Interestingly this inserts *nothing*, rather than `0000-00-00`

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: You need single quotes around the dates; they're string literals. Without that, you're telling it to insert 2012-02-20 which is 1990... because those are numbers and minus signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the quote `'` for the date string.

```
$data = array(
            'user_id'       =>  $user_id,
            'period_start'  =>  "DATE_ADD('$last_period_end', INTERVAL 1 DAY)",
            'period_end'    =>  "DATE_ADD('$last_period_end', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)",
            'cost'          =>  $cost
        );
```

Comment: thanks so much for that. everything is fine now! It didn't even occur to me at the time.